# Design Patterns and Prinicples

Tags: design-patterns, oop

I have recently experienced and understood the importance of "Design Patterns and Principles" implemented in our project. I was just wondering if you all would share the importance of Design patterns and principles, of how using them in your source code the project was enhanced, so that we can learn out of your vast programming experiences.

Also, do post some pointers and links for skill enhancement related to Design patterns and Principles.

Comment: this question (or the bunch of sub-questions) touches a lot of areas - can't be answered in its current form.. would have voted to close for being 'too all over the place'. If each poster replied with his subjective experiences... this thread would be one giant linked list of text globs.

Comment: @Gishu - Ya, its a big subject, its true. But what I feel is, instead of reading books or going through PDFs, it would be better and easy to learn if people share their experiences and tips. That is the purpose of this post . . .

Comment: @Gishu: Agreed - massively vague.

Comment: On the contrary, Design patterns ( a solution to a problem in a given context) are easier/better to learn from a book than from other peoples' (possibly customized/incorrect/unneccessary) application - you can pick up a copy of Head First DP and tell me if I was wrong. I agree that studying the code of masters would help (in the second/intermediate phase of learning) ; a beginner however won't be in a position to distinguish between the work of a master and a novice

Comment: @Gishu - Yup, I am already in that direction . . . Thanx . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check related links.

[Learning/Implementing Design Patterns (For Newbies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244706/learning-implementing-design-patterns-for-newbies)

[How to study design patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315000/how-to-study-design-patterns)

[How important are Design Patterns really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978489/how-important-are-design-patterns-really)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582715/how-to-start-recognizing-design-patterns-as-you-are-programming